# Regression: how to interpret different linear relations?

Tags: predictive-modeling, regression

I have three datasets, let's call them `X` and `Y1` and `Y2`. A scatterplot is produced out of them, with `Y1` and `Y2` sharing them same `X` dataset (or support).

**My question:** if the two regression lines are different in both slope and intercept, is there a way to evaluate if the `X` dataset has more influence on `Y1` or `Y2`?

Based on the image below, this is to say - **which Y dataset is more influenced by the X dataset?**

- Blue slope (Y1): -112
- Red slope (Y2): -90

**EDIT**

It is visible that an increase in X produces a decrease in both Y1 and Y2. My question could be interpreted as follows: **which Y dataset decreases the most, given the increase in X? Is the slope everything I need?**

Image:
[image]

Comment: Sorry for a noob question :)

What do you mean by *Y dataset is more influenced by the X dataset?*

Comment: It is visible that an increase in X produces a decrease in both Y1 and Y2. My question could be interpreted as follows: which Y dataset decreases the most, given the increase in X? Is the slope everything I need?

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I think ANCOVA is the technique you're looking for.  Pl have a look at the answer and let me know if it answered your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the Analysis of Covariance ([ANCOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_covariance)) analysis, which is used to compare two or more regression lines by testing the effect of a categorical factor on a dependent variable (y-var) while controlling for the effect of a continuous co-variable (x-var).

[Here](http://r-eco-evo.blogspot.in/2011/08/comparing-two-regression-slopes-by.html) is an example for carrying out the ANCOVA analysis using R.